# Forming an array from column values based on a different column value condition

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, average, multiple-columns

I have the following dataset.

1. 10
2. 20
3. 30
4. 40
5. 50
6. 60
7. 70
8. 80
9. 90
10. 100

My aim is to replace the values in Column 2 with the average of two successive values, when the value in Column 1 remains less than 5 and greater than 6. To be precise,in <5 range the values in Column 1 are 1,2,3 and 4 and corresponding column 2 values are 10,20,30,40. So, i want to take the average of (10,20)=15 and (30,40)=35. I want to do the same in the range >6 for Column 1, take the average of corresponding Column 2 values (70,80)=75 and (80,90)=95. I will not take the average of Column 2 values when Column 1 values do not fall in those two ranges (5 and 6) and corresponding Column 2 values (50 and 60) and finally create an array of Column 2 values based on these three conditions.

I tried the following approach:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data= pd.read_table('/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/Data.txt', dtype=float, header=None, sep='\s+').values
t=data[:,0]
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":t, "y":data[:,1]})
x=np.where(t<=4,data[:,1],np.nan)
x_1=np.nanmean(x.reshape(-1, 2), axis=1)
y=np.where((df.x>4)&(df.x<7), df.y,np.nan)
z=np.where(t>6,data[:,1],np.nan)
z_1=np.nanmean(z.reshape(-1, 2), axis=1)
A=np.concatenate((x_1,y,z_1), axis=0)
print(A)
```

I am getting the following output:
[ 15.  35.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  50.  60.  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  nan  nan  75.  95.]

My expected output is:
[ 15.  35.  50.  60. 75.  95.]

Any help on how to get around the np.nan in my code would be really helpful.

Comment: I don't quite get the expected output. You say, you want to replace the values in column 2, but your output will generate less elements.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I ran my code again, I am getting the output I mentioned above @Piinthesky

Comment: Your expected output has six elements, but you want to replace ten values. Or is your expected output a numpy array with six elements?

Comment: Yes, My output will be now 6 elements instead of 10, I am shrinking Column2 based on the three conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I genuinely have difficulties to see your bigger concept here. For your very specific problem, this would work:

```
import pandas as pd
#read your file
data= pd.read_table('test.txt', dtype = float, delim_whitespace = True, names = ["x", "y"])
#define rows you want to exclude
exclude_rows = set([5, 6])
#create new column with rolling mean of two rows
data["mean"] = data["y"].rolling(2).mean()
#overwrite rolling mean, when row should be excluded from calculating the average
data["mean"][data["x"].isin(exclude_rows)] = data["y"]
#filter data
A = data["mean"][(data["x"].isin(exclude_rows)) |  (data["x"] % 2 == 0)]
```

But what is your expected output, if you want to exclude for instance x = 4 and 6? Then you have several singular values, for which you didn't give any instruction, what should happen with them in the process of averaging.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, my concept is except for corresponding values of 5 and 6, all the other Column 2 values based on Column 1 (1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10) will be averaged over two successive values.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want

```
a=np.vstack((np.arange(1,11),np.arange(10,110,10))).T
b=(a[:-1,1]+a[1:,1])/2
indL=np.argmax(a[:,0]>5)-1
indH=np.argmax(a[:,0]>6)
out=np.hstack((b[:indL:2],a[indL:indH,1],b[indH::2]))
```